# Unexpected behavior with remove items from list

Tags: python

For starters, I'm new to python and coding in general.

I'm trying to remove desktop.ini files form a zip folder I am creating. I'm using the following to do this

```
if 'desktop.ini' in item:
     contents.remove(item)
     continue
```

However, the item in the list after desktop.ini is also getting removed and I have no idea why. Any ide why this is happening?

Here is the entire script if more context is needed

```
import shutil
import zipfile
import tempfile
from distutils.dir_util import copy_tree

def fileList(fileName):
    files = list()
    for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk(fileName):
        files += [os.path.join(dirpath, file) for file in filenames]
    return files

print("What version are these macros? ")
versNo = str(input())
path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
mac = 'macros'

with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as macfolder:
    copy_tree(os.path.join(path,mac),macfolder)
    with zipfile.ZipFile(os.path.join(path, "Release Assets",'Nautilus_Macros_'+versNo+'.zip'),'a') as maczip:
        contents = fileList(macfolder)
        #print(contents)
        for item in contents:
            #print(item)
            if 'desktop.ini' in item:
                    contents.remove(item)
                    continue
            #print(item)
            f = open(item,'r+')
            lines = f.readlines()
            f.seek(0)
            f.write('; Macro for the Nautilus 3D printer by Hydra Research \n')
            f.write('; Version: '+versNo+' \n \n')
            for line in lines:
                f.write(line)
            f.close()
            print(item)
            maczip.write(os.path.join(macfolder, item), os.path.relpath(item, macfolder))
    maczip.close()
```

Comment: You can't modify a collection while iterating over it.

Comment: The linked question marked as a duplicate is not really a duplicate; the solution is not to remove the item from the list at all. Just `continue` without removing it.

Comment: @kaya3 Good call. I've reopened the issue so you can point that out in an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sirens should blare and warning lights should flash any time you remove something from a list (or other collection) while you are iterating over it.

Consider how iterating over a list actually works: there is some variable (let's call it `i`) which keeps track of the index of the current item. On each iteration of the loop, `i` increases by 1, and the loop stops when `i >= len(contents)`.

When you remove an element from the list at the index `i`, all the elements after it are shifted left by 1, to fill the "gap" where the removed element was. The element previously at index `i + 1` is now at index `i`. *But `i` still gets increased by 1, ready for the next iteration,* and the next element you read comes from index `i + 1`. That element *used to be* at index `i + 2`, so you've skipped an element.

For this kind of reason, you should never add or remove elements from a collection while you're iterating over that collection in a `for` loop.

---

In this case, just using `continue` is enough to make sure that element doesn't get written to `maczip`; it skips the loop to the next element from `contents`, so you don't also need to remove the current element from `contents`. Change the code this way:

```py
if 'desktop.ini' in item:
    # don't do contents.remove(item)
    continue
```